# Can't get one python test to pass. Checking to see if value lays in a list, even if it is empty as well

Tags: python, list, function, assert

```
def contains(some_list: list[int], target: int)->bool:
for i in range(len(some_list)):

    if target in some_list:
        return True
    if target not in some_list:
        return False
    if len(some_list) == 0:
        return False

assert contains([1, 5, 2, 6, 9, 0], 5)==True, "5 is in the list"
assert contains([1, 10, 2, 6, 9, 0], 5)==False, "5 is not in the list"
assert contains([5, 1, 2, 6, 9], 5)==True, "5 is in the list"
assert contains([1, 2, 6, 9, 5], 5)==True, "5 is in the list"
assert contains([], 5)==False, "5 is not in an empty list"
print("All tests passed!")
```

I am able to get all tests to pass besides the last! I can't seem to find the issue! I believe it has something to do with the last line of my if statement not including the target. Am I wrong?

Comment: Putting aside the question regarding why you even use a for-loop: The last test never enters the loop since `range(len([]))` is empty. It then returns `None`. And/or your indentation is incorrect.

Comment: Your code just returns None when it comes to last case because it does not enter the loop at all

Answer (score -1):

This will pass the tests

```
def contains(some_list, target):
    return target in some_list

assert contains([1, 5, 2, 6, 9, 0], 5)==True, "5 is in the list"
assert contains([1, 10, 2, 6, 9, 0], 5)==False, "5 is not in the list"
assert contains([5, 1, 2, 6, 9], 5)==True, "5 is in the list"
assert contains([1, 2, 6, 9, 5], 5)==True, "5 is in the list"
assert contains([], 5)==False, "5 is not in an empty list"
print("All tests passed!")
```